# Does RFID-RC522 supoort tk4100 chip protocol ISO18000-2C 10 digital ID card?

Tags: rfid

I have ordered a starter kit and received RFID reader is

> RFID-RC522

module with one card and tag now I need more RFID card for my project and I can't find the supported card type for my project please can any one tell me supported card types and if this card supports my device this is the card type

> tk4100 chip protocol ISO18000-2C 10 digital ID number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MFRC522 on your kit is designed to communicate with ISO/IEC 14443 A/MIFARE and NTAG cards.

Search for `Mifare Classic` or `Mifare Ultralight` or `NTAG213`, `NTAG216` ... cards.

Comment: Thank you very much